# Cannot export a pandas DataFrame to Excel in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some help here, please.

An excel file needs to be updated, not overwritten. In particular, I need to add data to an Excel file (row by row) from an external data source (data from my own website), which I scraped using a Python script.

The following thus represents the excalty I wish to use in my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize an empty DataFrame with column names
columns = ['Client', 'Country', 'ID']
data_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# Simulate data extraction (this represent the data I get from my scrap loop in Python )
data_source = [
    {'Client': 'John Doe', 'Country': '@Italy', 'ID': '1234567890'},
    {'Client': 'Jane Smith', 'Country': '@San Marino', 'ID': '9876543210'},
]

# Here I loop through my data source/append data to the DataFrame
for row_data in data_source:
    data_df = data_df.append(row_data, ignore_index=True)


folder_path = "/foder/user/"
file_name = folder_path + "output_file.xlsx"

# Pandas Excel 
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')

#DataFrame to Excel
data_df.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)


excel_writer.save()
```

When I run the code, I got

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only
> Series and DataFrame objets are valid

Root cause:

I was investigating more about this error and its suggests that I am trying concatenate a string with an object that is not a string.

My question:

What coud be the best approach to solve this?

Comment: The [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) docs show you need to use `pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',mode='a')` to append. The loop only causes delays, you could have used `data_df=pd.DataFrame(data_source)` to create a new DataFrame from a dictionary

Comment: BTW `to_excel` appends an entire sheet at once, it doesn't add rows below the existing sheet. If you do want to append sheets, you need to specify what to do if a sheet already exists with [if_sheet_exists](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas-excelwriter). If you want to append rows to an existing table you'll have to load the existing data, concatenate the new dataframe and then save the sheet. An `xlsx` file isn't a text file you can append to, it's a ZIP package containing XML files

Comment: Another possibility is to use the `startrow` arguments to start writing after the existing rows.

Comment: Okay, Appreacite your time Panagiotis.